# How to display all users except current user?

Tags: 7, views

How to display all users in a view except the current login user?

I try to write some php code in contextual filter, but that not work. I think there is an easy way but I don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make a view that displayed all the users while excluding the current user.  Here is a screenshot of the settings I used:

[image]

Note that the important filter here is the "User: Current (No)".  That is the one you'll need to have.